# Animating the same block every time it gets activated again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website with a content carousel. Every time you select a next slide the yellow block with text is visible, when you leave the slide that block becomes invisible again. Now I want to animate that block every time it gets visible or invisible (like a fade-in or fade-out).

With both CSS animations and JQuery I can't seem to get it working multiple times. Especially because the block already animates on load.

Website link:
http://i280133.iris.fhict.nl/jongens/index.php

```js
$('.home .imagewrapper').css({
    'opacity': '0',
    'left': '-50px'
}).animate({
    left: "+=50px",
    opacity: 1
}, 1000, function() {
    $('.home .textwrapper').animate({
        top: "40px",
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('.home .swiper-slide-active .textwrapper').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000, function() {

        });
    });
});
```

```css
.home .swiper-slide .textwrapper {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in;
}

.home .swiper-slide-active .textwrapper {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide een">

            <div class="imagewrapper col-md-10">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/780x450" class="desktop">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" class="mobile">
            </div>

            <div class="textwrapper col-md-4">
                <h1 class="quote">Die nieuwe outfit was hard nodig.</h1>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide twee">
            <div class="imagewrapper col-md-10">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/780x450" class="desktop">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" class="mobile">
            </div>

            <div class="textwrapper col-md-4">
                <h1 class="quote">Hoe zit dat met uw huisstijl?</h1>
                <br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
                <br>
                <p class="leesmeer">meer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide drie">
            <div class="imagewrapper col-md-10">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/780x450" class="desktop">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" class="mobile">
            </div>

            <div class="textwrapper col-md-4">
                <h1 class="quote">Die nieuwe outfit was hard nodig.</h1>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide vier">
            <div class="imagewrapper col-md-10">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/780x450" class="desktop">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" class="mobile">
            </div>

            <div class="textwrapper col-md-4">
                <h1 class="quote">Die nieuwe outfit was hard nodig.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide vijf">
            <div class="imagewrapper col-md-10">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/780x450" class="desktop">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x500" class="mobile">
            </div>

            <div class="textwrapper col-md-4">
                <h1 class="quote">Die nieuwe outfit was hard nodig.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put a function fired when scrolled

.on( "scroll", handler )

and function would have a delay for animation(fade in)

Comment: can you show your jquery code for the scrolling effect ?

Comment: Looks like you are using swiper jQuery plugin, it has effect option to add effect to your slider. http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it to work. I combined the swiper API functions with some code i wrote myself :)